# Derived class should call static methods of base class but with overriden property

Tags: c#, class, overriding, abstract, derived

How do I do that?

The scenario:

```
abstract class DataAccess
{
    public abstract string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static DataTable ExecuteSql(string sql)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static object ExecuteStoredProc(string storedProcName, ...)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

abstract class DataAccessDb1 : DataAccess
{
    public override string ConnectionString = "SetDbSpecificConnectionStringHere";

    public static DataTable GetStuff()
    {
        // Call the method with the ConnectionString set HERE.
        return ExecuteSql("select * from stuff");
    }
}
```

I know it's know possible to set the connection string like in the derived class, but I want to keep it static, therefore I won't set the property in every method in the derived class... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: pass the connection string in as a parameter into the method.

- Fields don't behave polymorphically, so the declaration in `DataAccessDb1` is invalid
- `static` and polymorphism don't mix

So basically, if you want polymorphic behaviour, you should be using instance members. If you don't really need polymorphic behaviour, pass any variations (such as the connection string) as a parameter for the method.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be possible to make it a bit more elegant. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 0):

There is no static inheritance in C# so your goal of having the `ConnectionString` has a static member and override it won't work. Rethink your design - having `ConnectionString` as static really says this field should be the same on all your `DataAccess` instances since it is defined on the type itself.

Is there a particular reason you use static methods - using instance methods and setting the connection string in the constructor would work:

```
public class DataAccessDb1
{
    public string ConnectionString {get;set;}

    public DataAccessDb1()
    {
        ConnectionString = "SetDbSpecificConnectionStringHere";
    }

    public void DataTable GetStuff()
    {
        return DataAccess.ExecuteSql(ConnectionString, "select * from stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: The derived class should also be static so I can't use the constructor. :(

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you want it to be static?

Comment: Because I don't want to create dozens of objects that do my data actions. I find it comfortable to just call "Customer.GetAddress()" without instantiating "Customer". Saves me a lot "Customer c = new Customer()". Just a small example...

Answer (score 0):

What I think that you should only have a ExecuteSql method in the abstract class and all derived classes would implement ExecuteSql with their respective connection string,

```
    public abstarct string ConnectionString{get;set;}
```

can be removed from the base class.

Comment: Yep, that's what Jon said. But now I alsways have to pass the connection string as a parameter to ExecuteSql(). :/

Comment: Generally you should avoid using static, your problem can be solved by using a singleton and a factory pattern for making objects. You will have a singleton factory class manufacturing concrete DataAccessDb objects, you don't have to pass connectionstring in the arguments. you should just ask a singleton factory for concrete object of DBAccessDb1 which should have required connection string. I know its difficult to explain it in words but i don't have much time to write code now :(

Comment: What a bummer. That really sounds good, though I didn't unterstand much of it.